# ¿Cómo convertir un array JSON en un java.util.List utilizando Gson?

Tags: java, json, gson

> Tengo un `JsonObject` llamado `"datos"` con el siguiente contenido:
>
> ```
> {
>     "cliente": "127.0.0.1",
>     "servidores": [
>         "8.8.8.8",
>         "8.8.4.4",
>         "156.154.70.1",
>         "156.154.71.1"
>     ]
> }
> ```
>
> Yo sé cómo puedo obtener el array `"servidores"` con:
>
> ```
> mapping.get("datos").getAsJsonArray();
> ```
>
> Ahora necesito convertir ese objeto `JsonArray` en un objeto
>   `java.util.List`...
>
> ¿Cuál es la forma más fácil de conseguir esto?

---

Pregunta original: [Parsing JSON array into java.util.List with Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544133/parsing-json-array-into-java-util-list-with-gson)

Comment: Pregunta previamente contestada en : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544133/parsing-json-array-into-java-util-list-with-gson hay que evitar hacer esto para ganar puntos ya que no permite el desarrollo de nuevos colaboradores =(

Comment: @Elenasys sí, de hecho la pregunta la contesté yo en StackOverflow! Me pareció buena idea ponerla aquí porque es una pregunta que tiene muchas visitas y muchos votos, por lo que me pareció que potencialmente muchos usuarios podrían estar interesados en tener esta información en español... No he visto en ningún sitio que eso no se pudiera hacer (aunque he de reconocer que no he leído _toda_ la información), y desde luego no lo he hecho "para ganar puntos"... De todas formas, si no se pueden poner aquí preguntas que ya estén contestadas en SO, ¿cuál es el sentido de este sitio? No lo entiendo :|

Comment: Otros usuarios parecen estar de acuerdo con mi razonamiento...   
http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46/son-aceptables-las-traducciones-de-preguntas-de-stackoverflow-en-ingl%c3%a9s  
Ya que esta se trata de una pregunta que YO he contestado (no la estoy copiando "para ganar puntos", repito)

Comment: Aceptable porque estamos en beta privada, pero más adelante es mejor evitar esta práctica (responder con traducciones a preguntas legítimas sí está bien en cualquier caso). http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/129/23

Comment: @MikO - Si la pregunta no era tuya, tienes que hacer referencia a la pregunta original, porque sino, estas violando copyright. Esto es muy importante. Si no estas buscando puntos lo mejor seria marcar la pregunta como wiki, no?

Comment: @Konamiman - No puedes decir que una conducata es aceptable basado en tu propio post, jaja. Es mas la comunidad esta dividida en dos a este respecto. Pero si MiKO respondio esta pregunta me parece aceptable que traduzca su respuesta. Lo que si, tiene que hacer referencia a la pregunta original porque sino esta violando copyright. Y para mi seria incluso mejor si marcara la pregunta como wiki. La respuesta no, porque es todo produccion de el.

Comment: @Dzyann He incluido un enlace a mi post en Meta para no repetir aquí todo el razonamiento, no como argumento de autoridad. Y conste que yo no he votado negativo. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Muy sencillo, sólo se necesita seguir los siguientes pasos.

1. Crear el objecto `Gson`:

   ```
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   ```
2. Obtener el tipo (`Type`) de la lista que quieres construir, en este caso `List<String[]>` (Nótese que la clase `Type` es una clase estándar de Java localizada en el paquete `java.lang.reflect`):

   ```
   Type type = new TypeToken<List<String[]>>() {}.getType();
   ```
3. Convertir el objeto `JsonArray` en el objeto `List<String>` con:

   ```
   List<String[]> yourList = gson.fromJson(yourJsonArray, type);
   ```